# Pulso triangular como señal de impulso

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Tengo problemas en compilar este codigo, me sale error en la linea 5 y 14 la cual esta linspace, el error sale asi `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.`
Tambien quiero saber si la libreria signal es la apropiada para este tipo de código ya que soy nueva en esto

```
#Ejercicio 1.18

import os
os.system('cls')

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import signal as Bsig

N1 = 100
nvec1 = np.linspace(-N1, N1, num=2*N1)
N2 = 500
N3 = N2/10
nvec2 = np.linspace(1, N2, num=N3)
delvec = 1/nvec2
t = nvec1/N1
ix = 0
while ix < N3:
    delx = delvec[ix]
    ix = ix + 1
    u_t_p = Bsig.fn_unstep(t, delx)
    u_t_m = Bsig.fn_unstep(t, -delx)
    L_del_t = 1/delx*(1-abs(t)/delx) * (u_t_p-u_t_m)
    plt.plot(t, L_del_t, 'r')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: N3 = N2/10 da como resultado 50.0, y el tercer parametro(num) de np.linspace() solo acepta numeros enteros positivos, pasale un int() al N3 y todo deberia estar bien.
nvec2 = np.linspace(1,N2,num=int(N3))

Comment: Muchas gracias enserio, ahora el problema es que no se si estoy usando bien la libreria signal para las líneas 21 y 22.

Comment: signal no tiene un metodo "fn_unstep", sé sobre el codigo que estas escribiendo pero no sobre pulso triangular, pero te recomiendo que uses la libreria scipy donde hay un metodo especifico para esto: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.sawtooth.html

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias por la información.

Comment: Para los que puedan llegar aquí en un futuro, puedes hacer la división con // en lugar de / para no sacar decimales